# What is integral of $x^x$?

Tags: calculus, functions

I have no idea on how to approach this problem. I tried solving it by taking logarithm and then evaluating, but that won't serve the purpose I guess. Can someone please help?

Comment: $x^x=e^{x\log x}$, so I don't think its integral can be expressed in a closed form, or by means of elementary functions.

Comment: It is not integrable in terms of elementary functions

Comment: I even don't think that it could be integrated at all.

Comment: ["http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+x^x"]

Comment: [On a  related note.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream)

Comment: @Raskolnikov, beat me to it...

Answer (score 5):

For sure, as Dario commented, you could start with $x^x=e^{x\log x}$, replace $x\log x$ by $y$ and take the Taylor series of $e^y$ and then replace, in the resulting expression, $y$ by $x\log x$. You will then have $$x^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {x^n \log^n(x)}{n!}$$ and $$I_n=\int x^n \log^n(x)~~dx=\log ^{n+1}(x) \Big(-E_{-n}[-(n+1) \log (x)]\Big)$$ where appears, as one could expect, the exponential integral.

If we consider $\int_0^2 x^x~dx$, the value using numerical integration is $2.83388$. Considering the given expansion, one term will give $2.38629$, two terms $2.70706$, three terms $2.79964$, four terms $2.82640$, five terms $2.83244$, six terms $2.83363$, seven terms $2.83384$, eight terms $2.83387$, nine terms $2.83388$.

Comment: You are very welcome.